# Is it possible to create bulk of txt files in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to create thousands of file with txt extension in c++. Is it possible? I can not imagine how can i do that. If I write some code right here so you can understand what I want.

```
int main () 
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I want to generate a bulk of txt of files with this method. In addition I want to run these codes inside a for structure. At the end of the operation I must have 10,000 file and these file's names are like example1.txt , example2.txt , example3.txt ... You do not have to write code I just want to know how to do it. You can just share link to some tutorial.

Comment: All you need to do is write your above code fragment in a for loop, such that string name changes in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Here are the steps I suggest:

1. Use a [`for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) or a [`while`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) loop.
2. In each iteration of the loop construct the name of a unique file by using the loop counter. You can use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) or [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for that.
3. Use the code you already have to create a file in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    std::ofstream myfile;
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){

        myfile.open("example" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```